# Remaining travel time calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a bit confused with a time calculation problem, given average speed <km/h> and remaining mileage  for travel.

I saw in a book, where they give average speed <km/h> of 120 and remaining mileage  of 20, they say that the remaining travel time is: 1 hour(s) and 40 minutes.

But when calculating this I get 16 minutes i.e. dividing 20 miles (about 32 km) to 120 km/h.

Why is it that in the book they have a remaining travel time of 1 hour and 40 minutes?

Comment: Are you sure those numbers are correct?  Going a speed of 120 kilometers per hour for 1 hour and 40 minutes will result in a distance of 200 kilometers, which is definitely not 20 miles.  Your calculations are correct for the numbers you've given.

Comment: @DMcMor, you are right. I noticed they used Swedish mile: 20 mi = 200 km :-/
Then, my calculations are right. Thank you.

Comment: TIL there's such a thing as a Swedish mile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different measurements of miles.

The US mile is 1 mile = 1.60934 km

The Swedish mile is 1 mile = 10 km

In the problem stated, Swedish mile is used. So, the procedure to calculate is correct, if it is for the US mile.

Comment: Pedantic:  1 mile = 1.609344 km